# Cannot Access this from nested function in angular4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5, angular2-services

I have a component called abc and in that component I have three variable named title,Desc,Name and when I am trying to access it from nested function it gives me as undefined.

e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'abc',
  templateUrl: './abc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abc.component.css'],
  providers: [abcService]
})

export class abcComponent implements AfterViewInit,AfterViewChecked {

  title;
  Desc;
  Name;
  date=null;

test(){
this.title='a';
//work fine
}

test11(){

$('#cmg tbody').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.title= false;  //gives me an undefined
});

}

}
```

Comment: Just saying, mixing Angular with jQuery is not the best practice.

Comment: this is just because angular 5 not provided a data grid which I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you are losing the scope in your callback. Modify it to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that you keep `this`

```
$('#cmg tbody').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.title= false;
});
```

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the base object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an
>   object-oriented style of programming.

Comment: Instead of relying on a side-effect of arrow functions you should be passing the context with intend. Arrow functions also don't work in IE which means using the "side-effect" doesn't work there.

Comment: @Nope ok , what is the alternative way?

Comment: It will work with arrow function bcoz *this* in an arrow function refers to the lexical scope

Comment: @AnkitSatapara Arrow function will work fine though IMHO using them for event handlers seems a strange "solution" as `this` should be referring to the element the event was triggered on, i.e: `a.editor_edit`

Comment: @Nope Ok, Thanks for the solutions